# Get width of table cell in directive when that width is set dynamically in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

OK... I have a template:

```
<th width="{{setWidth(1)}}%">{{deal}}</th>
```

I have a directive:

```
.directive('tableheaders', function($window,$compile) {
    return function(scope) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');

    for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {       
        console.log(th[i].width); // returns "{{setWidth(1)}}%" need "100%"
    }
```

How do I compile the value of width being sent so I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$timeout` or the jqLite function `ready()` to wait for the DOM to be ready and the `{{setWidth(1)}}%` to have been evaluated.

With `$timeout`:

```
app.directive('tableheaders', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope) {
    $timeout(function () {
      var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');

      for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
        console.log(th[i].width);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

With `ready`:

```
app.directive('tableheaders', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.ready(function () {
      var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');

      for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
        console.log(th[i].width);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Or you can use `$interpolate` to perform the evaluation manually:

```
app.directive('tableheaders', function($interpolate) {
  return function(scope, element) {

    var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');

    for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {

      var expression = $interpolate(th[i].width);
      var width = expression(scope);
      console.log(width);
    }
  };
});
```